sw_vers not found when installing packages on miktex on macOS
When I try to install packages on miktex or try to update miktex itself, I get the error message "sw_vers not found" with no additional detail provided. I checked the sw_vers command by running it in the terminal and it worked. I've also reinstalled miktex console and restarted my computer. Any ideas on what this could be?

I wouldn't use miktex on macOS. Most macOS users will use some flavour of texlive, like mactex. This is thus much better tested and also tends to incorporate updates much faster then miktex.

Honestly, it is not worth looking at it. Better use macTeX, which provides very convenient access to the TeX system on macOS. This has also repeatedly been proposed here with same issue. Example: MiKTeX consistently failing macOS

If there are already other posts about the same issue, please add a link so we can mark this as duplicate.
